# How to get DayNames from language only in .NET

Tags: c#, cultureinfo, regioninfo

Assume that I only have a country code (en, de, fr) and I need to display the weekdays in this language.
I know about RegionInfo and CultureInfo - but I can't find a solution.
If I create a country info from (for an example) "en" I have no DateTime info in it.
It would also be OK to just take the first matching Region. For an example en-US for en or de-DE for de.

I don't know if there are differences in DayNames but I know there are some for the months.
de-DE Februar - de-AT Feber -- anyhow I don't care.
Event if it may be "a bit different" (to see Februar instead of Feber) - it is still German.

And that's what I want to achive - get en an write Monday - get de and write Montag...

Is there a way to create a region just from a language code?

Comment: I guess you can't use CultureInfo.CurrentCulture ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This piece may be helpful:  to go from "en" to the CultureInfo, a quicker way is

```
CultureInfo ci = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en")
```

For the second part, I believe you are asking for day names, so you would write

```
string[] names = ci.DateTimeFormat.DayNames
```

Comment: +1 - each neutral culture ("en", "de") is associated with a default specific culture ("en-US", "de-DE").

Comment: OK, that is better than my FirstOrDefault.

Comment: Thank you Jennifer - soooo easy :) and also thank you to Henk - runner-up slot :)

Answer (score 4):

It's usually when you say "I don't care" that you start fighting the APIs.

Anyway, this should work:

```
var list = CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.SpecificCultures);
var ci = list.FirstOrDefault(c => c.IetfLanguageTag.StartsWith("de"));

var ri = new RegionInfo(ci.Name);
Console.WriteLine("Today = {0:dddd MMMM yyyy}", DateTime.Today);
```

Comment: +1, but you should use `CultureTypes.NeutralCultures` rather than `SpecificCultures`.

Comment: @Randolpho: No, the next step is creating a RegionInfo and that throws when you use a neutral culture. We need a (random) specific culture for a language name.

Answer (score 1):

This will give you a list of cultures:

```
    Dim ci As CultureInfo
    For Each ci In CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.SpecificCultures)
        Console.WriteLine(ci.Name)
    Next
```

OUTPUT:
ar-SA
bg-BG
ca-ES
zh-TW
cs-CZ
da-DK
de-DE
el-GR
en-US
fi-FI
fr-FR
he-IL
hu-HU
is-IS
it-IT
ja-JP
ko-KR
nl-NL
nb-NO
pl-PL
pt-BR
ro-RO
ru-RU
hr-HR
sk-SK
sq-AL
sv-SE
th-TH
tr-TR
ur-PK
id-ID
uk-UA
be-BY
sl-SI
et-EE
lv-LV
lt-LT
fa-IR
vi-VN
hy-AM
az-Latn-AZ
eu-ES
mk-MK
af-ZA
ka-GE
fo-FO
hi-IN
ms-MY
kk-KZ
ky-KG
sw-KE
uz-Latn-UZ
tt-RU
pa-IN
gu-IN
ta-IN
te-IN
kn-IN
mr-IN
sa-IN
mn-MN
gl-ES
kok-IN
syr-SY
dv-MV
ar-IQ
zh-CN
de-CH
en-GB
es-MX
fr-BE
it-CH
nl-BE
nn-NO
pt-PT
sr-Latn-CS
sv-FI
az-Cyrl-AZ
ms-BN
uz-Cyrl-UZ
ar-EG
zh-HK
de-AT
en-AU
es-ES
fr-CA
sr-Cyrl-CS
ar-LY
zh-SG
de-LU
en-CA
es-GT
fr-CH
ar-DZ
zh-MO
de-LI
en-NZ
es-CR
fr-LU
ar-MA
en-IE
es-PA
fr-MC
ar-TN
en-ZA
es-DO
ar-OM
en-JM
es-VE
ar-YE
en-029
es-CO
ar-SY
en-BZ
es-PE
ar-JO
en-TT
es-AR
ar-LB
en-ZW
es-EC
ar-KW
en-PH
es-CL
ar-AE
es-UY
ar-BH
es-PY
ar-QA
es-BO
es-SV
es-HN
es-NI
es-PR
sma-NO
bn-BD
bs-Cyrl-BA
tg-Cyrl-TJ
en-SG
en-MY
mn-Mong-CN
prs-AF
wo-SN
rw-RW
qut-GT
sah-RU
gsw-FR
co-FR
rm-CH
mi-NZ
ug-CN
br-FR
moh-CA
arn-CL
ga-IE
ii-CN
sma-SE
sr-Latn-BA
quz-PE
ig-NG
kl-GL
lb-LU
ba-RU
nso-ZA
quz-BO
yo-NG
sms-FI
ha-Latn-NG
hr-BA
fil-PH
ps-AF
fy-NL
ne-NP
am-ET
iu-Cans-CA
quz-EC
si-LK
smj-SE
lo-LA
km-KH
cy-GB
bo-CN
se-SE
smj-NO
as-IN
ml-IN
se-FI
or-IN
sr-Cyrl-BA
bn-IN
en-IN
dsb-DE
tk-TM
smn-FI
oc-FR
es-US
se-NO
mt-MT
bs-Latn-BA
zu-ZA
xh-ZA
tn-ZA
tzm-Latn-DZ
iu-Latn-CA
hsb-DE

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.getcultures.aspx

Answer (score 1):

`DateTime.Today.ToString("dddd", new CultureInfo("zh-TW"))`

Above code will print Monday as 星期一 (Chinise locale).

Answer (score 0):

Dim days As String()
        Dim months As String()
        Dim cul As New System.Globalization.CultureInfo("de-DE")
        months = cul.DateTimeFormat.MonthNames
    days = cul.DateTimeFormat.DayNames

Comment: The problem is supplying the "-DE" part (for any given language).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

string culture = "your culture"

CultureInfo myCulture = new CultureInfo(culture);

DateTimeFormatInfo dtfi = myCulture .DateTimeFormat;

dayString = dtfi.GetDayName( your date here.. );

Charlie G

Answer (score 0):

As "de" is a NeutralCulture it won't be possible to get the DayNames out of the DateTimeFormat if you try CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("de").

I would suggest that you run the CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("de") in this case since it'll create a non-neutral culture...in case of "de" I got a culture of "de-DE" back from the .NET gods :D

```
    CultureInfo tmp = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("de");

    string[] names = tmp.DateTimeFormat.DayNames;
    foreach(string name in names)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(name);
    }
```

Comment: Haven't figure the fallback/lookup in this method though